# Is there a voice-based keyboard that can be used to type individual keys (instead of words)?

Tags: keyboard, software-recommendation, accessibility, voice-recognition

My arm is in a sling. I'm on Windows 10 now and then use speech recognition such as it is to clarify my question. Speech recognition leaves something to be desired no matter what platform you are on.

When you are a user of Ubuntu and you simply want to press keys  rather than trying to recognize entire words, the voice keyboard facility would nearly replace the keyboard driver permitting you to press individual keys with perhaps key combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

Most facilities for speech recognition don't let you simply enter key presses to whatever user interface presents itself because they don't grab control at the proper hardware abstraction level. That level in this case is the keyboard driver.
Such a facility may have been written for Ubuntu or Linux previously.  However it seems that no matter what combination of search terms I use I keep getting sent to various speech recognition facilities which cannot be used to press keys in arbitrary applications.

Does anyone know of such a facility?